# SonarQube runner made error on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I use Jenkins and plugin SonarQube and Sonar runner.
For SonarQube Runner installation in Jenkins, it made Warning like this.

**/home/abc/sonnar-runner-2.4 is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)**

of course I made /home/abc/ directory on the Jenkins Server.
so.. i ignore the warning and try to build tho..
it made error like this.

---

### SONAR ANALYSIS FAILED

FATAL: SonarQube runner executable was not found for sonar-runner-2.4
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

i cant figure out this problem 
is there anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Need some more logs please.

Answer (score 0):

When you config SonarQube Scanner in Manage Jenkins --> Global Tool Configuration --> SonarQube Scanner, besides select "Install automatically", you also need to add a installer.
See screenshot here:
[SonarQube Scanner --> Add Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1jut.png)